# вызвано исключение по адресу нарушение прав доступа при чтении - CreateProcess

Tags: c++, winapi

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define get_pause() cout << "Press any key to quit..." << endl; getch()

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION procInf;
    LPWSTR name = L"notepad.exe";

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, name, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &procInf))
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        get_pause();
        return 1;
    }

    get_pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Второй параметр `CreateProcess` должен быть *модифицируемой* строкой

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

> *lpCommandLine [in, out, optional]*
>   [...]
>   The Unicode version of this function, `CreateProcessW`, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.
>   [...]
>   The system adds a terminating null character to the command-line string to separate the file name from the arguments. This divides the original string into two strings for internal processing.

Поэтому надо

```
WCHAR name[] = L"notepad.exe";
```

**P.S.** Однако эксперимент показывает, что, как и сказано в MSDN, такой модификацией занимается только `CreateProcessW`, а с `CreateProcessA` вариант с литералом проходит. Но это не повод злоупотреблять.

**P.P.S.** Да и давно пора бы уже начать самому замечать, что в современном С++ нельзя

```
LPWSTR name = L"notepad.exe"
```

(даже если компилятор не ловит), а требуется

```
LPСWSTR name = L"notepad.exe";
```

Это вызвало бы ошибку компиляции при передаче в `CreateProcess` и тем самым намекнуло бы вам, что что-то вы делаете неправильно.

Comment: Вопрос ещё: а чем запуск через 1 параметр отличается от запуска через 2 параметр?

Comment: @DoctorShader: Тем, что в параметре 2 можно дополнительно указывать параметры командной строки. Если путь к выполнимому файлу содержит пробелы, то в параметре 2 этот путь надо брать в кавычки. В параметре 1 - не надо.